# Salary scheme, is HR is cheating?

Tags: statistics

I like to ask you about salary payment scheme by a company. Here is interesting points of this company salary scheme.

**New company payroll scheme**

1. Salary is credit on every 25th of every month.
2. Number of working days is 30 days flat.
3. A few people are joined on 29th of March (previous month)
4. Salary for April will be credited on 25th of April.
5. Total working day calculated by the company pay scheme is 28 (3 days from March and 25 days from April.

I already talked to the company payroll department that this is some kind of cheating in payroll scheme in compare to standard payroll scheme by other companies I worked for.

**Standard payroll scheme**

1. Joining date is 29 of March.
2. Joining date is 29 March
3. So working days is 3 day (29, 30, 31 of March)
4. Number of working days can be flat (30 days).
5. March salary is pro-rated. 3/30 so 1/10.
6. On April 25 payroll must be calculated on Calendar month (full month salary) because it is salary credit day. Not to calculate as 25 working days in April.

I have very doubt that combining 30 days per month calculation and payday 25th every month pro-rated calculation is for cheating salary calculation. 
I know there is some playing around payroll scheme to make some abuse or cheating. But in statistically I do not know how to prove that. Any help would do great for me.

Comment: I don't think that this is a question of mathematics.  It might or might not be a legal question depending on where you live.  The difference seems to just be whether the pay on the 25th should be regarded as for the month leading up to the 25th or the month containing the 25th.  I see a difference but not an obvious right or wrong.  I am not an expert in employment law; not even in my country let alone yours.

Comment: I am just looking for statistical evidence that it might be some abuse on calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Of course HR is cheating - that's their job.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they loose somewhat that way (if I understand the scheme correctly), in the long run at least.

Consider what would happen during a year with the second scheme: they will pay each employee $1$ months salary each month, resulting in $12$ months of salaries.

While the first scheme they will pay for the first $25$ days plus the last days of the previous month. This will be $(25+n)/30$ where $n$ is the number of days after the $25$th (that is $25+n$ is the number of calendar days previous month). Now if we add up the number of days the sum of $25+n$ would be $365$ (or $366$). The salary you get for one year is therefore $365/30$ months salaries which is slightly more than $12$.

Also note that for working partial month the salary that is for that part of the month will be the same in the two schemes, you will get $3/30$ month salary regardless (but maybe on different month).